# Trouble parsing array of objects returned from UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, google-apps-script

UrlFetchApp.fetch returns this arrav of objects I'm assigning to the variable results:

```
var results = [{"Category 1": "Benefits/Compensatio", "Category 2": "Compensation", "Category 3": "Recognizing You", "Processing Team": "myHR Tier 2 US CA"}];
```

To access the value of "Category 1" I'm using results[0]["Category 1"] which returns null. What am I missing? I can't figure out the right notation to access the key:value pairs in the zeroth object in the array.

Hopefully a simple answer and a dumb question.

Comment: I think that if the data is the object shown in the question, `results[0]["Category 1"]` returns `Benefits/Compensatio`. If the data is the string type, `undefined` is returned. So can you provide the script for replicating your issue?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. I suspected the same thing. Here is what I'm doing: UrlFetchApp.fetch('...URL...',options) then converting the response to JSON using JSON.parse(response). I assumed that would give me a JSON object to parse but I'm getting the null result when parsing the output from JSON.parse. What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What am I missing?`, in order to correctly understand about your situation, I asked whether you can provide the script for replicating your issue. But from your replying, it seems that you cannot do it. So I cannot understand about your situation. By this, I cannot think of your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found a solution!

Add a line like `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);`

or this `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`

after your `var results = ...` line

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/scripts/examples/fetch-resources
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response